# Is there a way to condense this into 2 columns ? COUNT(column_name)

Tags: select, count, where-clause

```
SELECT COUNT(title) AS SH
FROM movies
where genre = 'SH';

SELECT COUNT(title) AS CH
FROM movies
where genre = 'CH';

SELECT COUNT(title) AS ADV
FROM movies
where genre = 'ADV';

SELECT COUNT(title) AS COM
FROM movies
where genre = 'COM';

SELECT COUNT(title) AS DR
FROM movies
where genre = 'DR';

SELECT COUNT(title) AS SF
FROM movies
where genre = 'SF'
```

Comment: what do you mean by condense into 2 columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT count(*), genre
FROM movies
GROUP BY genre;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?

SELECT genre, COUNT(title)
FROM movies
GROUP BY genre